# Java. Error al llamar a una clase

Tags: java

En una tarea de la universidad estoy teniendo problemas al probar una de las clase ya que no me deja llamarla. No me deja utilizar ni `Banco.listarDescybuerto();` ni `his.listarDescubierto();`

```
public class Banco {

    Cliente[] cliente;
    Empleado empleado = new Empleado();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Empleado empleado = new Empleado();
        Cliente[] cliente;
        cliente = new Cliente[50];

        int longitudArray = 50;

        for (int i = 0; i < (longitudArray); i++) {
            cliente[i] = new Cliente();
        }

        // Crea con valores aleatorios los vvalores del límite descubierto y el
        // saldo
        for (int i = 0; i < (longitudArray); i++) {
            int aleatorioSaldo = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (0 - (5000 + 1)) + (5000));
            int aleatorioDescubierto = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (0 - (300 + 1)) + (300));
            cliente[i].setSaldo(aleatorioSaldo);
            cliente[i].setLimiteDecubierto(aleatorioDescubierto);
        }

        // Lector del array que tiene el saldo de los clientes
        System.out.println("El saldo de los clientes es: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < longitudArray; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ". " + cliente[i].getSaldo() + " ");
        }

        // Lector del array del límite descubierto de los clientes
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("El limite descubierto de los clientes es: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < longitudArray; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ". " + cliente[i].getLimiteDecubierto() + " ");
        }

        // Prueba de la función de transferir
        System.out.println(" ");
        empleado.transferir(cliente[1], cliente[2], 30);
        System.out.println("El saldo actual del emisor es: " + cliente[1].getSaldo());
        System.out.println("El saldo actual del recepetor es: " + cliente[2].getSaldo());

        Banco.listarDescubierto(); // AQUI ESTÁ EL PROBLEMA
    }

    public Banco(Cliente[] cliente, Empleado empleado) {
        super();
        this.cliente = cliente;
        this.empleado = empleado;
    }

    public Cliente[] getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente[] cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public Empleado getEmpleado() {
        return empleado;
    }

    public void setEmpleado(Empleado empleado) {
        this.empleado = empleado;
    }

    public void listarDescubierto() {
        for (int i = 0; i < (cliente.length); i++) {
            if (cliente[i].descubierto()) {
                System.out.println(
                        "El saldo esta descubierto, el saldo de " + cliente[i] + " es " + cliente[i].getSaldo());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Para poder acceder a dicho método , se debe crear una instancia de la clase principal  *Banco* ya qué no es un método estático y posteriormente acceder al método.

```
Banco sol = new Banco ();
sol.listarDescubierto();
```

La forma en la que presenta funcionará siempre y cuando el método sea *static* , es decir

```
public static void listarDescubierto() {  ... }
/* Para acceder la forma */
listarDescubierto();
/* O */
Banco.listarDescubierto();
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que **definir como estatico** el método para que pueda ser accesado de la forma que deseas (`Banco.listarDescubierto();`):

```
  public static void listarDescubierto() {
        for (int i = 0; i < (cliente.length); i++) {
            if (cliente[i].descubierto()) {
                System.out.println(
                        "El saldo esta descubierto, el saldo de " + cliente[i] + " es " + cliente[i].getSaldo());
            }

        }
    }
```

de otra forma si no esta definido el método como static, tienes que realizar una instancia para acceder al método:

```
 Banco banco = new Banco ();
 banco.listarDescubierto();
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes crear la instancia del objeto banco de la siguiente manera `Banco banco = new Banco();`

En programación orientada a objetos un objeto es una instancia de una clase.

En tu código remplazarías `Banco.listarDescubierto();` por `banco.listarDescubierto();`

Ya que si tiene que se como tu ejemplo vuelves el método `listarDescubierto()` estático:

```
 public static void listarDescubierto() {
        for (int i = 0; i < (cliente.length); i++) {
            if (cliente[i].descubierto()) {
                System.out.println(
                        "El saldo esta descubierto, el saldo de " + cliente[i] + " es " + cliente[i].getSaldo());
            }

        }
    }
```

Aun que en la practica no seria lo mejor.